# Functional derivatives in Feynman Path Integral

Tags: packages

Is there any package that can simplify functional derivatives in path integrals? For instance the expression (integrate over, $x,y,z,u,v,r,s$):

$$\int\delta_{J_{A}^x}\delta_{J_{B}^x}\delta_{J_{B}^x}\int{J_{B}^y}\Delta^{yz}_B{J_{B}^z}\int{J_{B}^u}\Delta^{uv}_B{J_{B}^v}\int{J_{A}^r}\Delta^{rs}_A{J_{A}^s},$$
where $$\delta_{J_{A}^x}:= \frac{\delta}{\delta {J_{A}^x}}$$ and 
$$\Delta^{rs}_A:=\Delta_A(r-s).$$

Comment: Probably, this is a duplicate of [Can we teach Mathematica about functional differentiation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14523/245). The package you're looking for may be `FeynCalc` in Rolf Mertig's answer.

Comment: Yes kind of related but I would like to solve the problem with Kronecker deltas, I think they suffice for this problem.