# Avoid writing explicit form of operator

Tags: symbolic, operators

I would like to evaluate the following (simplified) expression with Mathematica :

$\frac{\delta}{\delta J} \exp[(J(x)+K(x)) \Delta (J(x)+K(x))]$
where $\Delta$ is a differential operator independent of $J$, depending on $x$.

The thing is, I don't want to write an explicit expression for $\Delta$ since it is not necessary. Is there a way to do that ? I apologise if the question is very basic, but I'm quite new to Mathematica and I have a hard time understanding how it works. Thanks in advance.

Edit : here are a few additional details.

The operator $\Delta$ is a differential operator of the form $\Box - mˆ{2}$, typical KG but not in a flat metric (if that is helpful for the question).

I need to actually compute :

$$\exp \left(- \frac{i}{4} J_4 \left(i \frac{\delta}{\delta J} \right)ˆ4 \right) \exp[(J(x)+K(x)) \Delta (J(x)+K(x))] $$

so I thought about expanding the exponential in a sum and apply the sum on the exponential on the right to see if a pattern could be found, in order to get an analytical expression for that. Doing the differentiation by hand is quite long and tedious, so I wanted to see whether Mathematica could help me or not.

Comment: Looks very similar to Feynman diagram expansions. It's not solving your question directly but could be a useful way , rather than explicit differentiation.

Comment: Please desrcibe in some more detail what you mean. Do I understand correctly that for instance δ/δU { U(x) (Δ.U(x)) } would be the Operator P = (Δ.U(x)) + (U(x) Δ) where in the last term the differential Operator Δ acts on something to the right of P?

Comment: I took a guess at what you want, and answered based on that. Instead, you may also find [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14531/245) useful (but I didn't manage to get general symbolic results easily with that).

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze : The operator is really Δ, being applied on (J+K).

Answer (score 2):

One could go very low-level and try to define an operator just in terms of basic properties such as linearity, but I chose to go for a middle ground and assume that we're dealing with a linear *differential* operator. The coefficients in the `operator` are called `a[i]` where `i` is a symbolic summation index corresponding to the order of the derivative in each term (see below). Also, I introduce a *test function* `g[x]` with which the expression in the question is to be integrated. This formulation allows me to directly use the `VariationalMethods` package:

```
Clear[a,j,k,g];
Needs["VariationalMethods`"];
operator = Function[f, Sum[a[i] D[f, {x, i}], i]];    
VariationalD[Exp[(j[x] + k[x]) operator[j[x] + k[x]]] g[x], j[x], x]
```

> $$(-1)^i \frac{\partial ^i}{\partial x^i}\left(g(x) \sum
>    _i a(i) (j(x)+k(x)) \exp \left((j(x)+k(x)) \sum _i
>    a(i)
>    \left(j^{(i)}(x)+k^{(i)}(x)\right)\right)\right)\\+g(x
>    ) \sum _i a(i) \left(j^{(i)}(x)+k^{(i)}(x)\right)
>    \exp \left((j(x)+k(x)) \sum _i a(i)
>    \left(j^{(i)}(x)+k^{(i)}(x)\right)\right)$$

This is as far as one can get with my purely symbolic sum for the differential operator. Any more specific information could be inserted in `operator`, making it possible to get concrete results. In the result, `g[x]` is then the placeholder for the function on which the whole expression acts in the operator sense.

Comment: I see. You are writing down a generic expression for a linear operator, so in my case since I know its form you would suggest to implement it too even thought it is not strictly necessary. I'll also check the VariationalMethods package, I was unaware of that, thanks.

Comment: Your edit looks much more complicated since it starts with the fourth functional derivative, and also the component notation seems to indicate that $J$ is a four-vector. I assumed that the main question was how to write a generic differential operator, but I think you're looking for a coordinate-independent way of working with a *specific* operator in variational calculus. Maybe you'll find what you need in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19938/245). Regarding my answer, I guess I could have simply set `g==1` to make it simpler, but anyway it's not going to help much...