# How obtain the n-th derivative of a function with an implicit variable?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm interested in obtain the analytical n-th derivative with respect to the variable $x$ of an implicit function like $V(h(x))$ where $h(x)$ is an implicit equation and can not be obtained the variable $h$ in terms of $x$. But we know that $\frac{dh}{dx}=f(h)$, so that we can make the derivatives with respect to $h$ using the chain rule:

$\frac{dV(h(x))}{dx}=\frac{dV(h)}{dh}\frac{dh}{dx}=\frac{dV(h)}{dh}\cdot f(h)$

$\frac{d^2V(h(x))}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2V(h)}{dh^2} \left(\frac{dh}{dx}\right)^2+\frac{dV(h)}{dh}\frac{df(h)}{dh}f(h) =\frac{d^2V(h)}{dh^2} f(h)^2+\frac{dV(h)}{dh}\frac{df(h)}{dh}f(h) $

.
.
.

And here is the problem, how can be obtained this in Mathematica?, since using the command `D[V[h[x]], {x, n}]` it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this what you are after? `h /: Derivative[1][h] := f@*h; D[V[h[x]], {x, 2}]`

Comment: I think this has been covered extensively in a [previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14523/can-we-teach-mathematica-about-functional-differentiation)

Comment: I think that it's not exactly the same. Here we want only use the chain rule and express the derivatives in x with respect to h. Because as we know the functions of V(h) and f(h) then we can evaluate numerically putting up the value of h.

Comment: Ah it doesn't work me the code, gives me an error on the character "@", I don't know why.

Comment: what about `h /: Derivative[1][h] := Composition[f,h]; D[V[h[x]], {x, 2}]`, probably you don't have v10.

Comment: Ah now it works,  my version of Mathematica was 9, a lot of thanks!