# Use of variational operator,  in Mathematica

Tags: variational-calculus

I am working in Hamilton's principle.
Part of deriving the equation of motion is to use the delta operator () which can be operated just like a differential operator.
It is not the function VariationalD in package VariationalMethods.

A post was posted regarding the same subject but it seems that who asked the question found the answer somewhere else. The previous question is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178566/use-of-variational-operator-in-wolfram-mathematica-version-11-0?newreg=36ee136a94ef4c75a33bfcba273df757).

Example on the equation is:

> T= 0.5 Mu'^2

applying the delta operator

> T=M u'  u'

I need to find the first and second variation of this function w.r.t the dependent variable.

regards

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, `VariationalD` does perform integration by parts which might be unwanted.

For this simple univariat case, one can hack together a quick function `myVariationalD`:

```
Clear[δ, myVariationalD]
myVariationalD[expr_, f_[x_]] := Module[{maxDerivative},
  maxDerivative = Max @ Cases[expr, Derivative[m_][f][x] :> m, Infinity];
  D[expr, f[x]] δ[f[x]] + 
   Sum[D[expr, Derivative[m][f][x]] δ[Derivative[m][f][x]], {m,
      1, maxDerivative}]
  ]
```

The example you have given can then be computed as

```
expr = 1/2 \[DoubleStruckCapitalM] u'[t]^2;
myVariationalD[expr, u[t]]
(* \[DoubleStruckCapitalM] δ[u'[t]] u'[t] *)
```

Comment: Thank you Natas, 

What about below equation:

>>  T = 0.5 M D[u[t], t]^2
>> \[Delta]T = D[T /. {u -> u + s \[Delta]u}, s] /. s -> 0

Comment: @aymanzayed Sorry, but I don't quite understand what you are asking. Perhaps you can modify your question and explain in detail the expected output for a given input and I can then edit my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on Hamilton's Principle to derive the governing equation of beam. After evaluating the strain and kinetic energy, I am combining both the energies. Now I want to apply the variational operator on my Hamilton's principle. The strain energy and kinetic energy terms contain the five variables such as u[x,t], v[x,t], w[x,t],Theta[x,t] and Phi[x,t].

How I can get the governing equation with these five variables? The Strain energy terms are as follows:

```
D00 ks \[Theta][x, t]^2 + D00 \[Phi][x, t]^2 + B00 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t]^2 - 2 D00 \[Phi][x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(v\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] + D00 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(v\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t]^2 - 2 D00 ks \[Theta][x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] + D00 ks 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t]^2 - 2 B10 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] + B20 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t]^2 - 2 B01 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] - 2 B01 \[Theta][x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] + 2 B10 \[Phi][x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] + B11 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] + B20 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] + B11 \[Theta][x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] + B20 \[Theta][x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] - 2 B20 \[Phi][x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] + B11 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t]^2 + 2 B11 \[Theta][x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t]^2 + B11 \[Theta][x, t]^2 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t]^2 - B11 \[Phi][x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t]^2 - B20 \[Phi][x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t]^2 - B11 \[Theta][x, t] \[Phi][x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t]^2 - B20 \[Theta][x, t] \[Phi][x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t]^2 + B20 \[Phi][x, t]^2 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t]^2
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to the original question, rather a question in its own right.  You should post it as a question and delete this 'answer'.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/106222)