# How to find Euler equation of complex function by the textbook definition

Tags: variational-calculus

In the help [`document`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/tutorial/VariationalMethods.html), we know that `EulerEquations[y[x] Sqrt[1 + Derivative[1][y][x]^2], y[x], x]` can solve the following Euler equation of equation :$$∫_{x_{\min}}^{x_{\max}}y(x)\sqrt{1+y'(x)^{2}} dx$$

But how can we solve the Euler equation in the following mixed case with integral and others terms by using MMA?
[image]

The result of the variation of the above functional in the textbook is :
[image]

Using the boundary conditions ${w(0)=0,w(L)=0,w'(0)=0}$, we can reduce the above results to:
[image]

I did this, but it turned out to be obviously wrong:

```
EulerEquations[
 Integrate[(1/2 \[DoubleStruckCapitalE]*\[DoubleStruckCapitalJ]*
      w''[x] - q*w[x]), {x, 0, L}] + M*w'[L], w[x], x]
```

I need to find the first derivative of a functional according to the above textbook definition.

And the results in this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14523/can%20-%20we%20-%20teach%20-%20mathematica%20-%20about%20-%20functional%20-%20differentiation/14531%20#14531) don't meet my needs.

Comment: I think you may need MMA's code to find the first derivative of functional by definition. I'm also interested in this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as much as I see from documentation the function `EulerEquations` takes the Lagrangian as the argument, rather than the action. Therefore, there should be no `Integrate`statement. Just the expression staying under the integral. Second, `EulerEquations` do not treat the boundary terms such as `M*w'[L]`. And as a minor note, you have forgotten to square the `w''[x]` term. Like this it is

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"];
EulerEquations[(1/2 e*j*(w''[x])^2 - q*w[x]), w[x], x]
```

[image]

which is reasonable. You will have to add the boundary condition by hand.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I want to know if there is any way to achieve the $\delta$ result form in the textbook.

Comment: Not that I know.